# Difference between “an” and “neben”

Tags: difference

[image]

Can someone explain what is the difference between *an* and *neben* in German for this picture?

> Der Stab ist an dem Würfel.
>
> Der Stab ist neben dem Würfel.

Comment: On the left, the two objects are touching, on the right they are not.

Comment: Yes, but what is the suitable translation in english? "near" for both of them?

Comment: If you're searching for an English expression, you are in the wrong place here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why the picture does not answer your question?

Comment: I understand the difference in the picture, but i don't understand when to use "an" and when "neben" because in my native language they have the same translation. Always when 2 objects touch - "an" and when don't touch - "neben" ?

Comment: In dem Bild ist kein Stab.

Comment: @Tom Pretty much, yes. But note that it's possible to use "neben" when objects not touch, though. See my comment below Ingmar's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Neben" also implies that the object are sort of sideways to one another.

Compare:

> Anna steht am Fenster.

|_ Anna _|

> Anna steht neben dem Fenster.

|_______| Anna

---

In many cases, only one of the two prepositions would actually be used.

> Die Uhr hängt an der Wand. --> *good*
>
> Die Uhr hängt neben der Wand. --> *odd, and meaning something else, like Anna at the window.*

Or:

> Anna sitzt neben mir. --> *good*
>
> Anna sitzt an mir. --> *distinctly odd.*

---

Regarding the picture in your question: The word "neben" would work for both cases. The difference between these two prepositions isn't easy to put into pictures. I hope my examples can help a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it's *neben* = "next to, beside" and *an* = "adjacent to". The main difference is the space between the to objects: *an* requires that they literally touch.

Comment: Funny enough, that some dictionaries define "adjacent" as "next to". I guess the nub is that, as you correctly said, "an" requires that objects touch each other. On the other hand, "neben" does not exclude touching. Ex. "Wer von den beiden? Der vor oder neben dem Haus?" -> Both may touch the house, it's just a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 1):

> Der Stab ist an dem Würfel.

I would translate that to something like *the rod is at the cube* as in touching and in immediate range.

> Der Stab ist neben dem Würfel.

The rod is right next to (not in the literal sense) / really near / beside  the cube. Physically they are side by side but not touching. There is a distance between them.